# Python sqlite3 .fetchmany(batch_size) while loop exiting after one loop

Tags: python, sqlite, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
import openai
import sqlite3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def clean_and_save_descriptions_subset(days_old = 7, num_reivew = 1000, batch_size = 50):
    api_key = os.getenv("OPEN_AI_API_KEY")
    sql = f"""
    SELECT e.mp3_url, e.episode_description 
    From episodes e 
    JOIN shows s 
    ON e.itunesid = s.itunesid 
    WHERE published_date > STRFTIME('%s', 'now') - ({days_old} *24 *60 *60)
    AND s.num_reviews > {num_reivew}
    AND e.clean_episode_description is NULL
    """
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db/chatterpulse.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)

    batch_no = 0
    while True:
        batch = cursor.fetchmany(batch_size)
        if not batch:
            break
        
        print(batch_no)
        mp3_urls = [row[0] for row in batch]
        episode_descriptions = [row[1] for row in batch]

        cleaned_descriptions = clean_descriptions(episode_descriptions, api_key)

        for mp3_url, cleaned_description in zip(mp3_urls, cleaned_descriptions):
            update_sql = f"""
            UPDATE episodes
            SET clean_episode_description = ?
            WHERE mp3_url = ?;
            """
            cursor.execute(update_sql, (cleaned_description, mp3_url))

        conn.commit()
        batch_no += 1

    conn.close()

clean_and_save_descriptions_subset()
```

The code all works as expected, getting and setting data to the database as expected. However, it then exits the loop after exactly one batch. I've tried a couple of different itterations of this code and still get the same issue.

Chatgpt and I are both at a loss. Apologies for the lack of reproducibility, but not really feasible.

Comment: And yes, I am sure there is enough data. It returns exactly 50 results (batch_size) every time I run it, and can be run multiple times, grabbing 50 more every time.

Comment: Hint: After `cursor.execute(update_sql, ...`, from which SQL query will `cursor.fetchmany` return data?

Comment: ugh you're right. Thank you.